# Calling a ros service function from another one

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to find a way to call a service function from another one. To explain the situation, let's assume the following ROS messages and services:

```
# mypack/msg/MyRosMsg.msg
uint8       v1
# ... other definitions

# mypack/srv/MyRosSrv1.srv
mypack/MyRosMsg  msg

# mypack/srv/MyRosSrv2.srv
mypack/MyRosMsg  msg
# ... other definitions
```

I have a ROS service function as below:

```
bool my_service_1(mypack::MyRosSrv1::Request &req, mypack::MyRosSrv1::Response &req)
{
  // do some processing
  return(true);
}
```

and I want to call `my_service_1` from the second service function by copying `msg` member of `MyRosSrv2` into `MyRosSrv1` as below:

```
bool my_service_2(mypack::MyRosSrv2::Request &req, mypack::MyRosSrv2::Response &req)
{      
  mypack::MyRosSrv1 srv1;
  srv1.msg = req.msg;
  // how to call properly my_service_1?
}
```

**Edit 1**
Both service functions are inside one node. The service `my_service_1` performs a processing that I am trying to avoid repeating the code in the service `my_service_2`.

**Edit 2**
As *tbh* answered, the following changes is the trick to make it work:

```
bool my_service_2(mypack::MyRosSrv2::Request &req, mypack::MyRosSrv2::Response &req)
{      
  mypack::MyRosSrv1 srv1;
  srv1.request.msg = req.msg;
  my_service_1(srv1.request, srv1.response);
  // do other processing
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66992/calling-a-ros-service-function-from-another-one/) by [Rasoul](https://answers.ros.org/users/1477/rasoul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-07-10**:
Does the standard way of calling a service not work out of my_service_2?

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-07-10**:
srv1.msg doesn't exist. You mean srv1.request.msg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if you mean for these two service callbacks to be in the same node or not...

If they are, the service callback is still a function, right? So you should be able to call `my_service_1(srv1.request, srv1,response);` like you would any other function.

If they're not in the same node, there's no rule that says you can't call one service from another service.  Just know that services are blocking.  So the caller of my_service_2 would have to wait for my_service_2 to finish before continuing execution, and my_service_2 won't finish until my_service_1 finishes.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Clancy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20877/clancy/) on 2015-04-29**:
It's as simple as tbh makes it out to be - just call that function name from inside the other service. No need to specify an address for the srv.request or srv.response, they are already included. So it looks like this:

serviceCallBack(some_srv.request, some_srv.response)